# Complex Gaussian random vector, vec operator and expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-matrices

Let $\mathbf{w} \sim \mathcal{CN}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{I})$ be a $N$-dimensional, complex Gaussian random vector with zero mean vector and identity covariance matrix.

I have to evaluate the following matrix:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{C} = E\{[\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^H)][\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^H)]^H\}
\end{equation}
where $E\{\cdot\}$ is the expectation operator, $\mathrm{vec}(\cdot)$ defines the vectorization operator obtained by stacking the columns of a matrix on top of one another, and $H$ indicate the Hermitian operator. Consequently, $[\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^H)]$ is an $N^2$-dimensional complex random vector.
Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your notation E{???} needs clarification.

Comment: Here some additional clarification. $E\{\cdot\}$ is the expectation operator, $\mathrm{vec}(\cdot)$ defines the vectorization operator obtained by stacking the columns of a matrix on top of one another, and $H$ indicate the Hermitian operator. Consequently, $[\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^H)]$ is an $N^2$-dimensional complex random vector.

Comment: You have an expression [vec...][vec...].  What does this mean?

Comment: The expression $[\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^H)][\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^H)]^H$ represents the $N^2 \times N^2$ matrix obtained by the standard (row-column) matrix product of the vectors $\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^H)$ and $[\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^H)]^H$. In particular, let $\mathbf{a}$ be a complex column vector, $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}^H$ represents the matrix whose entries are defined as $[\mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}^H]_{ij}=a_ia_j^*$.

Comment: I don't think I can help you further.  I have never encountered an expectation for a matrix.  Could it mean expectation for each element?